# Apply a filter to a React array and display the filtered results

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to filter an array written in React Js but so far, I have been unsuccessful getting an undefined error. I want to filter some images that have value lower than 10.

The way I tried to apply the filter looks like:
`{this.images.filter((image:any={}) => image.value < 10)}`
but something isn't right.

What is wrong with my filter and how it can be written to have a working code?

```
export class somePageImages{

  images: any[] = [
    { img: 'http://www.someimage.com/', value: 4, title: 'Image 1', description: 'A description 1' },
    { img: 'http://www.someimage.com/', value: 6, title: 'Image 2', description: 'A description 2' },
    { img: 'http://www.someimage.com/', value: 10, title: 'Image 3', description: 'A description 3' },
  ]

  render() {
    return (
      <Host>
        <ol>
          { this.images.map((image:any={}) =>
            <li>
            <img src={image.img}></img>
            <h1>{image.title}</h1>
            <p>{image.description}</p>
          </li>
          )}
        {this.images.filter((image:any={}) => image.value < 10)}
        </ol>

      </Host>
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: You are filtering the array within your render function + after already having printed it in this.images.map(.. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to put the filter in a different position to work properly:

```js
this.images.filter((image:any={}) => image.value < 50).map((image:any={})
```

This way it's working properly without any `undefined` error